# Dates/months calculation

Tags: python, datetime

My below working code calculates date/month ranges, but I am using the Pandas library, which I want to get rid of.

```
import pandas as pd
dates=pd.date_range("2019-12","2020-02",freq='MS').strftime("%Y%m%d").tolist()
#print dates : ['20191101','20191201','20200101','20200201']

df=(pd.to_datetime(dates,format="%Y%m%d") + MonthEnd(1)).strftime("%Y%m%d").tolist()
#print df : ['20191130','20191231','20200131','20200229']
```

How can I rewrite this code without using Pandas?

I don't want to use Pandas library as I am triggering my job through Oozie  and we don't have Pandas installed on all our nodes.

Comment: What's your assumptions here - no imported libs at all? Or e.g. you are good with import of `datetime`?

Comment: You should stop calling `.tolist()` on these objects. I don't know why you're doing that in the first place, because you are effectively dropping the library and passing the data back as basic python objects

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski ah, I've re-read the question. Apologies, it seems you're correct (though I'm now totally baffled)

Comment: I mean, you can create a list comp that keeps adding on a `timedelta` with an increasing number of hours. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi. I don't want to use Pandas library as I am triggering my job through Oozie now and we don't have Pandas installed on all our nodes. datetime import is fine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas offers some nice functionalities when using datetimes which the standard library datetime module does not have (like the frequency or the `MonthEnd`). You have to reproduce these yourself.

```
import datetime as DT

def next_first_of_the_month(dt):
    """return a new datetime where the month has been increased by 1 and
       the day is always the first
    """
    new_month = dt.month + 1
    if new_month == 13:
        new_year = dt.year + 1
        new_month = 1
    else:
        new_year = dt.year
    return DT.datetime(new_year, new_month, day=1)


start, stop = [DT.datetime.strptime(dd, "%Y-%m") for dd in ("2019-11", "2020-02")]
dates = [start]
cd = next_first_of_the_month(start)
while cd <= stop:
    dates.append(cd)
    cd = next_first_of_the_month(cd)


str_dates = [d.strftime("%Y%m%d") for d in dates]
print(str_dates)
# prints: ['20191101', '20191201', '20200101', '20200201']


end_dates = [next_first_of_the_month(d) - DT.timedelta(days=1) for d in dates]
str_end_dates = [d.strftime("%Y%m%d") for d in end_dates]
print(str_end_dates)
# prints ['20191130', '20191231', '20200131', '20200229']
```

I used here a function to get a datetime corresponding to the first day of the next month of the input datetime. Sadly, `timedelta` does not work with months, and adding 30 days of course is not feasible (not all months have 30 days).
Then a `while` loop to get a sequence of fist days of the month until the stop date.
And to the get the end of the month, again get the next first day of the month fo each datetime in your list and subtract a day.